# How to give a board indices algebraic notation?

Tags: python, chess

```
board = [
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
['|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|', '|__|'],
]
```

I am printing a board for chess that will have pieces 'wN', 'wK' 'wB', etc and I want to be able to use algebra notation for the movement of the pieces.  For exampled the first square that is at board[0][0] would represent 'a8'  and at board[7][7] would represent 'h1'.
edit: changed 8 to 7

I'm tried looping through the list but am unable to set each "square" to a algebraic notation.

Comment: Have you tried nested loop? https://pynative.com/python-nested-loops/ Technically a single loop can be used too but it's far more annoying to write

Comment: What have you tried? How does it fail to work?

Comment: You mentioned looping "through the list", can you show us the code you tried? It will help us understand a bit better what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple mapping of the letter to a value (row) and a calculation on the numeric part (column).

Assuming the algebraic coordinates are valid (there are no explicit checks here) then you can just do:

```
board = [['|__|'] * 8 for _ in range(8)]

def coords(a: str) -> tuple[int, ...]:
    return 'abcdefgh'.index(a[0]), 8 - int(a[1])

print(coords('a8'))
print(coords('h1'))
```

**Output:**

```
(0, 0)
(7, 7)
```

Another approach is to build a dictionary that can be used as a map:

For example:

```
amap = {}

for r, R in enumerate('abcdefgh'):
    for c, C in enumerate(range(8, 0, -1)):
        amap[f'{R}{C}'] = r, c

print(amap['a8'])
print(amap['h1'])
```

**Output:**

```
(0, 0)
(7, 7)
```